# PHP function to get current URL isn't dynamic on Twitter

Tags: javascript, php, url, dynamic, twitter

I'm trying to use a function so that every news article on my site shows the reactions on Twitter to that link. I'm trying a PHP function for getting the current URL, but it only returns it for one link, every other article on the site shows the same results.

This is what i'm trying:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=<?php  echo curPageURL();?>" data-widget-id="481435876400984065">Tweets sobre "@vivamovilcl"</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

So the strange thing is... it works for whichever first URL I try, and when I open any other URL it shows the results for the first one. It's like it's not refreshing on every article.

Help anyone?

This is curPageURL:

```
<?php function curPageURL() {  $pageURL = 'http';  if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")  $pageURL .= "s";}  $pageURL .= "://";  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];  } else {   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];  }  return $pageURL; } ?>
```

What happens is that it gets all tweets with (curPageURL) links perfectly. But it's like if the Twitter Widget locks it. Life if it limited the query to only one variation instead of letting it give me dynamic results for each page

Comment: What does `curPageURL()` look like?

Comment: There, i just added it and the symptom

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `curPageURL()` and your site urls look like exactly, the most likely problem is that you are trying to send a real url as a query parameter.

You should encode a url as it contains characters that are not valid for a query parameter value and / or might contain characters that terminate the current parameter value like a space or a `&` character:

```
q=<?php echo urlencode(curPageURL()); ?>
```

Comment: @Robguerra Well, based on your function, this is the solution :-) Can you add a complete url to a page and the (encoded...) link to twitter?

Comment: Do you mean that I input the code I wrote so that you can see it not working correctly?

Comment: @Robguerra I would like to see the complete url and the generated html twitter link of a page that is not functioning correctly. You can replace the domain name if you want, but leave the rest intact.

Comment: Short URL: http://t.co/9hNFJdlGUm // Complete URL: http://www.vivamovil.cl/noticia/7/tendencias/6232/tomarse_muchos_selfies_significaria_que_tienes_poca_actividad_sexual/2014_06_23/